# Simple jQuery arithmetic

Tags: jquery, math

Theoretically speaking, if I had a list of unordered items

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Link1</a></li>
    <li><a>Link1</a></li>
</ul>
```

How I could do the following with jQuery?

1) Find the width of each individual `a` element

2) Find the width of each individual `li` element

3) Subtract the width of each child `a` element from the width of it's parent `li` element

4) Then add the total to each parent `li` element

This doesn't work:

```
$('ul > li').each(function() {
  var liWidth = (this).width();
  var aWidth = ('ul > li > a').width();
  var subractedWidth = parseFloat(liWidth) - parseFloat(aWidth);
  var newWidth = subtractedWidth + parseFloat(liWidth);
  $(this).css('width',newWidth);  
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and $('ul > li > a) note ('ul > li > a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use the `$` in a few spots, and you are trying to get the `<a>` width that is within the specific `<li>` you are in, so you shouldn't requery the entire DOM. This would do it:

```
$('ul > li').each(function() {
    var liWidth = parseFloat($(this).width());
    var aWidth = parseFloat($(this).find('a').eq(0).width());
    $(this).width((liWidth - aWidth) + liWidth);
});
```

Comment: Thanks again for help with the syntax

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
$('ul > li > a').each(function () {
    var li = $(this).closest('li'), 
        liWidth = li.width(),
        aWidth = $(this).width();

    li.width(liWidth + (liWidth - aWidth));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot some $.

```
$('ul > li').each(function() {
  var liWidth = $(this).width();
  var aWidth = $(this).find('a').width();
  var subractedWidth = parseFloat(liWidth) - parseFloat(aWidth);
  var newWidth = subtractedWidth + parseFloat(liWidth);
  $(this).css('width',newWidth);  
});
```